# How to remove spacing between spliced images

Tags: html, space

Hey I made an image in Photoshop for an email newsletter. I sliced the image and added links to the images I want clicked, but when I send it in an email there are spaces between the images. How can I remove the spaces? Here is the coding.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>email_template_1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- ImageReady Slices (email_template_1.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="650" height="801" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="images/ttcc_01.jpg" width="650" height="65" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/ttcc_02.jpg" width="507" height="33" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <valign=top align=left width=33><a href="http://ttchallenge.blogspot.com"><img src="images/ttcc_03.jpg" width="33" height="33" border="0" alt="Blog"></a></td>
  <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/ttcc_04.jpg" width="10" height="33" border="0" alt="space"></td>
        <td>
            <valign=top align=left width=33><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/217569431593349/"><img src="images/ttcc_05.jpg" width="33" height="32" border="0" alt="Facebook"></a></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/ttcc_06.jpg" width="67" height="33" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/ttcc_07.jpg" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="images/ttcc_08.jpg" width="650" height="25" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="images/ttcc_09.jpg" width="650" height="162" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="images/ttcc_10.jpg" width="650" height="347" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/ttcc_11.jpg" width="504" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/ttcc_12.jpg" width="146" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/ttcc_13.jpg" width="324" height="72" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6"><valign=top align=left width=280><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/take-the-challenge/id468178150?ls=1&mt=8"><img src="images/ttcc_14.jpg" algin="left" width="280" height="72" border="0" alt="Click Here for more Information!"></a></td>
<td>
            <img src="images/ttcc_15.jpg" align="left" width="46" height="72" border="0" alt=""></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
            <img src="images/ttcc_16.jpg" width="650" height="95" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="324" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="180" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="10" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="33" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="46" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End ImageReady Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

and the site 
file:///Users/Dad/Dropbox/Apps/site44/ttc.site44.com/ttcc.html

Comment: add hspace=0 attribute to them

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to see your "site" when it lives on your *local file system*, as given by the `file:///` URI scheme name.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Photoshop is creating tables, and poor ones at that, you have a different issue. I would recommend that you apply the following style to your table:

```
#Table_01 {
  border-collapse: collapse:
}
```

That should fix the problem.

But if you weren't using tables, you could still have the same issue. This is because the spaces between the images are whitespace. They occur because your server doesn't optimize the HTML output. The reason this is a problem is because images and spaces can both be interpreted as having the CSS property `display: inline`. (I know some browsers don't do that to images, but when they do, this kind of thing happens.)

The solution I've used is to strip out all whitespace from between tags when it matters. Here's a sample function for doing that.

```
    function stripSpaceBetweenTags(container) {
            var rex = />\s+</gm;
            var htmlString = $(container).html();
            htmlString = htmlString.replace(rex,"><");
            $(container).html(htmlString)
    }
```

The `container` argument is a string that can be used as a valid jQuery selector. What happens is that it strips all cases of whitespace (spaces, tabs, linefeeds, etc.) between tags *if there is only  whitespace between those tags*. This is important: if you have other characters, you don't want them stripped out.

Think of it as an *ad hoc* optimizer. You don't have to do this to the whole page, and it's probably better if you don't. But if you have a container that holds images which have to be tight, tight, tight, this is a good workaround.

Comment: In a stylesheet. Otherwise, add it as a style tag in the table element: `<table id="Table_01" width="650" height="801" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">`. By the way, note that adding a height to a table is futile, since tables ignore that. If the content is bigger or smaller, they stretch to adapt.